# Optional parameters in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a common function:

`function getUrl() {
    return Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/";
}`

But sometimes I need to use parent frame to get url, like this:

`function getUrl() {
    return window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/";
}`

Can I declare this common function with possibility to pass `window.parent.` if I need it? 
And if the parameter is not passed, use the common implementation.

Comment: Sure, pass it as a parameter to `getUrl`?

Comment: All arguments are optional in JavaScript. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a param:

```
function getUrl(_use_parent){
    let url;
    if(_use_parent)
       url = window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
    else 
       url = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();

    return url + "/api/data/v9.0/";
}
```

If you just call getUrl(), _use_parent is undefined so it use the else statement.

[edit] And if you really want to pass window.parent

```
function getUrl(_window_parent){
    let url;
    if(_window_parent)
       url = _window_parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
    else 
       url = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();

    return url + "/api/data/v9.0/";
}
```

But if _window_parent isn't the correct object you could get a JavaScript error.